# Google adsense in iphone application

Tags: iphone, adsense

I'm trying run example of the adding at the Google Adsense .
The application I got from [here](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/ios/fundamentals.html).
But I have the error : 
2011-06-21 19:43:30.356 BannerExample[799:207]  Invalid Request: {
    errors = "Cannot determine request type. Is your ad unit id correct?";
    "google.afma.notify_dt" = 1308674610352;
    type = unknown;
}
What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

I also found a rogue space character in the adMob publisher id field located in the AdWhirl Apps interface.  The space was preceding " " character rather than a trailing space.  I wish AdWhirl would fix it on their end as this would have saved me many hours.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is with your Ad Unit Id, have you checked that it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you still have this issue, or maybe others who search for it:

For me, the issue was a rogue *space* character (" ") in the SDK Key (*Publisher ID*).
I am using AdWhirl, so I enter the AdMob SDK Key there, and I pasted it with an extra space at the end. 
When I removed the extra space, it worked.

Hope this helps.